# Update table with 2 join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update table which refers to two more tables.

Here's my select code to validate which rows will be updated.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    txsh AS t1 
        INNER JOIN div AS t2 ON t2.store = t1.ro_no
        INNER JOIN temp_db AS t3 ON t3.bpn = t1.sku_id
                   AND (t3.div IS NULL OR t3.div = t2.div)
                   AND (t3.s_num IS NULL OR t3.s_num = t1.ro_no)
```

[image]

This is the result of the 3 tables that I joined. Column 'div' is from table div which depends on ro_no while 'bpn, s_num, created_by' is from table temp_db.

Now I want to update all selected rows from my select code. Here's my update code.

```
UPDATE       txsh
SET          price = '0'
FROM         txsh AS t1
             INNER JOIN temp_db AS t2 ON t1.sku_id = t2.bpn
             CROSS JOIN div AS t3
             CROSS JOIN txsh
WHERE        (t2.div IS NULL OR t3.div = t2.div)
             AND (t2.s_num IS NULL OR t2.s_num = t1.ro_no)
```

I have three instances for the update. It depends on temp_db(bpn, s_num, div)

1. if s_num and div is null, update txsh where sku_id = bpn
2. if s_num is not null and div is null, update txsh where sku_id = bpn and ro_no = s_num
3. if s_num is null and div is not null, update txsh where sku_id = bpn and [ro_no]'s div value from table div[t2] is equals to temp_db's [div] value.

I'm thinking that the error is on instance [3]. Is there any way to correct my where clause for instance [3]?

Comment: Why on earth are you cross joining to txsh?  If you remove this cross join and change the UPDATE to be to "t1" instead then does your query work?

Comment: I'll make that more explicit; if you are happy that your first query works as intended then just remove the "SELECT *" from the start of it, replace this with "UPDATE txsh SET price = '0'" and you should be good to go.  A CROSS JOIN will just bring back every row in that table, so your second query will just update every record in txsh, the rest of the query is entirely redundant, and will probably be ignored by the optimiser anyway.

Comment: It's perfectly normal for two completely different queries to have different results.   Now if the same deterministic query returned different results, then that would be unexpected.

Comment: Hi there, I already tried to do that but it still updates all rows. I think that the problem is (t2.div IS NULL OR t2.div = t3.div) for this, I only want to update rows from txsh where t1.ro_no = t2.s_num and where the (ro_no) div is equals from t2.div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is getting too long for a conversation, so I will put it into an answer instead...

This is your original query, slightly reformatted to make it easier to read:

```
SELECT  
    t1.*
FROM    
    txsh t1 
    INNER JOIN div t2 ON t2.store = t1.ro_no
    INNER JOIN temp_db t3 ON t3.bpn = t1.sku_id 
        AND ISNULL(t3.div, t2.div) = t2.div 
        AND ISNULL(t3.s_num, t1.ro_no) = t1.ro_no;
```

If you run that query it will return a certain number of rows, it might return every row from txsh, or it might return a subset of rows as there are two constraints (INNER JOIN conditions).

Then there is the added complexity that those INNER JOINs might bring in more than one record from txsh, so the row count might end up being higher than the number of rows in txsh.  For example, there might be 10 rows in div where store = 10 and one row in txsh where ro_no = 10 (I don't know your data, maybe this isn't possible?).  In that scenario you could have 10 duplicated rows from txsh for each single row of data where store = 10.

So my first question, is how many rows are returned by this query, and is this the expected result?  Ideally you don't have duplication issues, and the answer is that the query returns somewhere between zero and the number of rows in txsh.

Your update query should now be as simple as:

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    price = '0'
FROM    
    txsh t1 
    INNER JOIN div t2 ON t2.store = t1.ro_no
    INNER JOIN temp_db t3 ON t3.bpn = t1.sku_id 
        AND ISNULL(t3.div, t2.div) = t2.div 
        AND ISNULL(t3.s_num, t1.ro_no) = t1.ro_no;
```

When you run this it will tell you how many rows were updated, is this the same number of rows that your SELECT query returned?

If you can answer those two questions then we can hopefully move on to resolve this issue?

Okay, I am still slightly in disbelief that the SELECT query returns 7 rows and the UPDATE updates 10 rows... but let's try this as a starting point.  I just wrote your logic out as simply as possible.  If this works then we can probably refactor the query a bit?

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    price = '0'
FROM    
    txsh t1 
    INNER JOIN div t2 ON t2.store = t1.ro_no
    INNER JOIN temp_db t3 ON t3.bpn = t1.sku_id 
WHERE
    --Case 1
    (t3.div IS NULL AND t3.s_num IS NULL)
    --Case 2
    OR (t3.div IS NULL AND t3.s_num IS NOT NULL AND t3.s_num = t1.ro_no)
    --Case 3
    OR (t3.div IS NOT NULL AND t3.s_num IS NULL AND t3.div = t2.div);
```

So the INNER JOIN to temp_db is now just on bbp to sku_id, as this is constant in your three cases.  I added the rest of the logic for each case into the WHERE clause.

I would try running this as a SELECT query first, then try the UPDATE?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still updates all rows. Originally, 7 rows must only be update. the query updates all 10 rows

Comment: I think that my problem is on ISNULL(t3.div, t2.div) = t2.div

t1 contains 'ro_no' that has 'div' value from t2. I want to update, rows where t3 column 'div' is equal to t1 (ro_no) 'div' value.

Comment: Do you have any rows in [temp_db] that have a NULL value for both [div] and for [s_num]?  This is the bit that seems potentially problematic.  Also, when you say it updates all ten rows, have you checked this, or are you just seeing a "10 rows affected" message when you run the UPDATE?  Seeing as you don't seem to have much data is there any chance you could add this into your question?

Comment: yes, I have null values for both [div] and [s_num]. I'm seeing "10 rows affected" I would edit my question then. Thanks for giving time for this.

Comment: Hi Richard, I already edited my question. Please see if it made my question cleared.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! I just changed UPDATE
    t1
to UPDATE
    txsh
. I also removed the 'cross join' that is always added by SQL when I run your query. Thank you!

Comment: Just a question, why does the query doesn't run when executing it at first or some tries. It says "column or expression price cant be updated" then "invalid object t1" and then it would add "cross join t1" on the from clause of the query. I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why you are seeing CROSS JOIN being added, or why your query wouldn't run the first time you try to execute it.  I assume that you are either using Entity Framework or something similar to run this query, in which case that's way out of my comfort zone.